# Display image file from database using Entities Asp Net MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I know tis is not a new question, but I've looked at all the topics related and coudn't find my answer.
My proble is that I have stored image data into sql db, but can't display them on edits or index (MVC 5). Can you please help me, thanks in advance.
Here are my codes:

**CONTROLLER**

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "DrvId,FullName,Address,Postcode,Contact,Email,County,File,Date")] DriverReg driverReg, HttpPostedFileBase[] files)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    /*Lopp for multiple files*/
                    foreach (HttpPostedFileBase file in files)
                    {
                        /*Geting the file name*/
                        string filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                        /*Saving the file in server folder*/
                        file.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Content/UploadedFiles/" + filename));
                        string filepathtosave = "UploadedFiles/" + filename;
                        /*HERE WILL BE YOUR CODE TO SAVE THE FILE DETAIL IN DATA BASE*/
                    }

                    ViewBag.Message = "File Uploaded successfully.";
                }
                catch
                {
                    ViewBag.Message = "Error while uploading the files.";
                }

                db.DriversReg.Add(driverReg);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(driverReg);
        }
```

**MODEL**

```
namespace HopeRemovalsFinal.Models
{
    public class DriverReg
    {
        [Key]
        public int DrvId { get; set; }
        public string FullName { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string Postcode { get; set; }
        public string Contact { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string County { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Upload)]
        [Display(Name ="Upload File")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage ="Please choose file to upload")]
        public string File { get; set; }
    //    public string FileName { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    }
    public class DriverDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public DriverDbContext()
            : base("VanRemovals")
        {
        }

        public static DriverDbContext Create()
        {
            return new DriverDbContext();
        }

          public DbSet<DriverReg> DriversReg { get; set; }

    }
}
```

**DETAILS VIEW**

```
            <dt>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.File)
            </dt>

            <dd>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.File)
            </dd>
```

**DATABASE RESULTS**

```
 Create New
FullName    Address     Postcode    Contact     Email   County  Upload File     Date    
John    manchester  M32 7DD     098764587   john@hotm.com   Lancashire  uk_map.png  19/04/2016 00:00:00     Edit | Details | Delete
```

The **UploadedFiles folder** is empty but the file has been saved on db.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: When you say "file data on db" and "file has been saved", are you talking about the file itself being saved to the db? Or are you saving the location on the file system as a string to that field "File"

Comment: HI guys,yes the file has been saved on the database, but can't display on details view

Comment: Sure? Or have you saved name only??

Comment: Also, from the code you show, we never see you assign the File field on your passed in DriverReg object.

Comment: foreach (HttpPostedFileBase file in files): files is probably null

Answer (score 1):

I found several errors in your code. So... this is my solution:

Model:

```
[DataType(DataType.Upload)]
[Display(Name = "Upload File")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please choose file to upload")]
[NotMapped]
public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }

public string FileName { get; set; }
```

View:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.File, new { type = "file" })
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Create(DriverReg driverReg)
{
    ...
    var file = driverReg.File;
    var fileName = "~/Content/UploadedFiles/" + file.FileName;
    file.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(fileName));
    driverReg.FileName = fileName;
    ...
}
```

Detail View:

```
<dt>
    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.File)
</dt>
<dd>
    <img src="@Model.FileName" />
</dd>
```

Comment: `driverReg.FileName` is set to an absolute path using MapPath, making it unusable for the img tag. Better to store a relative path.

Answer (score 0):

It seems odd that `Create` allows multiple files, while `class DriverReg` only has a `string File` (or FileName - not clear at the moment) that *isn't* a collection.

I'd say change `Create` method to accept a single file object.
If necessary also adjust the form to Post/Upload only one file.

Then, inside `Create` change this:

```
string filepathtosave = "UploadedFiles/" + filename;
```

to this:

```
driverReg.File = "UploadedFiles/" + filename;
```

You may need to change more that we're not seeing here, but I think doing all the above should make it better already.

Comment: Thanks Peter, but I changed for the above, and still only saves on database, not on UploadedFiles folder and can't display images either.

Comment: @prezequias He is right though. Your model only allows one "File" which we can only assume you intend to store the file path in this field and not the binary file data. You are passing in a posted file array and looping through them. Are you just expecting one file?

Comment: Does saving the file cause an Exception? If so, check the access rights for that folder. Or if no Exception occurs then maybe it is saved, but not where you are looking for it.

Comment: Yes, I know what you mean, I want want to pass one file, thanks

Comment: No, there is no Exception, it goes strait through, I've checked and it not saved anywhere.

Comment: When stepping through debugger while you were making sure an exception wasn't occuring, did you check what Server.MapPath(...) is evaluating to at runtime?